# Unable to send email when view has links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I am using ruby 1.9.3p194 and Rails 3.2.3.

I am facing problem while sending emails whose template has a link in it. I have written following code:

invitation_mailer.rb

```
def event_invitation(user, event)
  @user = user
  @event = event
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Invitation to participate in #{@event.name}   event")
end
```

event_invitation.html.haml

```
Hello,

%br
%br

Your friend #{@event.user.full_name} has invited you to participate in #{@event.name}   event. If you want to accept
this invitation, use the following link: 

= link_to calendar_index_url, calendar_index_url

%br
%br

#{t('shared.team')}
```

user.rb

```
def xyz
   ...
   InvitationMailer.event_invitation(self, event).deliver
end
```

If I remove the link line in the view, I am able to receive emails but not with the link inside the view. But the log shows that an email has been sent.

LOG

```
 Sent mail to abhimanyu@gmail.com (6117ms)
 Date: Fri, 02 Nov 2012 20:59:33 +0530
 From: invitation@dev.tld
 To: abhimanyu@gmail.com
 Message-ID: <5093e6dd6a275_14f733fc536034cd444087@Abhimanyus-iMac.local.mail>
 Subject: Invitation to participate in new event event
 Mime-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

 Hello,
 <br>
 <br>
 Your friend Abhimanyu Kumar has invited you to participate in new event event. If you   want to accept
 this invitation, use the following link:
 <a href="http://localhost:3000/calendar">http://localhost:3000/calendar</a>
 <br>
 <br>
 Dev Team
```

Any help to figure out the problem would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your spam folder?  Send to another email address?

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify the ActionMailer `default_url_options` in your environment config file?  Either in `config/environments/development.rb` or `config/environments/production.rb` (depending on the environment you're working on), make sure you include the following:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "example.com" }
```

See more info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#label-Generating+URLs